# Prevent postback of page in iframe from causing main page postback asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, postback

I am building an application that features a file uploader contained in an iframe. The uploader uses a second button to trigger the actual upload event. The upload event works, but when I click the upload button, it causes the page which contains the iframe in which my uploader is shown to refresh as well. The uploader and the offending upload button are both contained in the page being shown in the iframe, and the iframe itself is included in my main page this way:

```
<iframe id="uploaderFrame" src="FileUploader.aspx"></iframe>
```

I have tried wrapping the iframe in an UpdatePanel with ChildrenAsTriggers set to True, but the problem persists. Both my uploader page and my main page are in the same application.

The weird part is, this only happens if the user has selected files to upload. If the Upload button is clicked with no files posted in the uploader, the main page doesn't postback.

To be clear: I have zero problem with the page in the iframe doing postbacks. This is exactly what should be happening. Its the page containing the iframe doing postbacks that's the problem. How can I stop this?

EDIT: After further struggle, I have determined that the problem lies with that moment when files posted to the FileUpload control are actually saved to the server. I found that if I commented out the line of code where this actually happens, the parent page doesn't refresh when the Upload button is clicked.

The offending line looks like this:

```
file.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), name));
```

...where "file" is the name I give to the individual HttpPostedFile object contained in the PostedFiles collection, which is contained in the File Upload control. "Path" is the folder path to which the file should be saved, and "name" is the name under which to save the file.

So: is there another way to code this particular function that will keep the FileUploader's activity isolated to its own page, as it should be? Because I've even gone so far as to try to keep the parent page from refreshing using Javascript, and nothing's working.

EDIT 2: The issue is now resolved, but I'm still left with questions. After trying multiple alternatives (Ajax Tool Kit etc) with no success, I opened a copy of my project in Visual Studio 2017 -- I had been building it in VS2015 previously -- and spun it up in the debugger. And the bloody file uploader worked the first time. No unwanted postbacks, no hassle.

So it looks like the problem was with my development software, though I can't imagine what was going wrong exactly. But a solved problem is a problem solved.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Does the iFramed content contain any sort of [framebreaker script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) or anything that references `window.top`?

Comment: @John Wu There are no scripts such as you describe. I even tried running the application after commenting out all references to client-side code in my uploader page, and the issue still persists.

Comment: Are you submitting the page by clicking a button or by pressing the enter key?

Comment: @John Wu I am submitting the page by clicking the Upload button

Comment: I have also tried setting EnableViewState and EnableSessionState to true on my main page. No joy with either.

Answer (score 0):

Try that in your web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```